# Doctrine Query Builder ACOS function cannot be found

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I want to calculate distance in my custom repository class. The problem is that Doctrine throws exception while processing ACOS function:

```
[Syntax Error] line 0, col 70: Error: Expected known function, got 'ACOS'
```

Here is the query:

```
public function findLocation($latitude, $longitude)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    return $em->createQueryBuilder()
                    ->select('((ACOS(SIN('.$latitude.' * PI() / 180) * SIN(p.latitude * PI() / 180) + COS('.$latitude.' * PI() / 180) * COS(p.latitude * PI() / 180) * COS(('.$longitude.' – p.longitude) * PI() / 180)) * 180 / PI()) * 60 * 1.1515) AS distance')
                    ->from('StrictPlaceBundle:Poi', 'p')
                    ->add('orderBy', 's.distance ASC')
                    ->getQuery()->getResult();    
}
```

What can be wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ACOS is [not supported by DQL](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#functions-operators-aggregates). You could add it yourself of course (see [Adding your own functions to the DQL language](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language)).

Also, MySQL implementations of trigonometric functions you need are part of [DoctrineExtensions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions):

- [the test](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/tests/Query/Mysql/TrigTest.php)
- [functions](https://github.com/beberlei/DoctrineExtensions/tree/master/src/Query/Mysql)